# copyTo is failing to copy data

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a pretty simple problem that is for some reason killing me. I have the following script which should just autofill a formula down column O, then copy the values to column P (excuse my amateur coding):

```
function processData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastWorkDate = dateCheck();
  sheet.getRange('O1').setValue("=index('"+lastWorkDate+"'!O:O,match(B1,'"+lastWorkDate+"'!B:B,0))");
  sheet.getRange('O1').autoFillToNeighbor(SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  freeze();
};

function freeze() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange('P1').activate();
  sheet.getRange('O:O').copyTo(sheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

However, the copying just isn't doing anything. The script will successfully autofill O:O, but will fail to copy the values to P:P.

Manually running `freeze()` itself after running `processData()` (and thus already having O:O filled) works fine, so I figured it might be running too quickly and added the `Utilities.sleep(1000)`, however, that's not helping either.

Comment: Hi there, first of all it seems like you might have copied something wrong from your original code?  Look at the last line of `processData()`, after `freeze();`.  Second, maybe try using `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` before calling `freeze();`, as that will ensure all pending changes to the spreadsheet are made.

Comment: @Mark you're right, that was a piece of code on the following line I had commented out. Have no idea how that got in there. Anyways, `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` did the trick and even allowed me to remove the `sleep`. Thanks! If you can reply as an answer I can credit you.

Comment: Okay, glad to hear it worked for you, @Tock!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `processData()` function, use the `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` function just before calling `freeze();`.  This will force any pending changes (such as updates to a large number of cells) to finish right away.  See the API documentation for more information:  [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)